# Should DAL classes be public?

Tags: c#, class, architecture, interface

Say I've got a DAL that multiple applications use to access the same data. The DAL defines its own classes and interfaces for dealing with that data, but should the applications using the DAL be working with those classes, or just the interfaces?

Another way; should it be:

```
List<Product> products = MyDAL.Repository.GetProducts();
```

or:

```
List<IProduct> products = MyDAL.Repository.GetProducts();
```

Is it good or bad that each application utilizing the DAL will have to create its own implementation details for Product?

Comment: Why would the application need to have its own implementation details? It could use the (private) implementations defined by the DAL, via the (public) interfaces.

Comment: Actually the biggest issue I have with the above is the use of List instead of IList. That's more likely to cause issues than IProduct instead of Product.

Comment: Ian, et al, thanks, but please keep in mind the code above was for illustrative purposes only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing interfaces around, instead of classes, is one (very good) thing. Making your DAL classes private is a different (and not necessarily good) thing.

For instance, what if one of the applications that use your DAL want to change the behavior of Product slightly? How can you subclass or decorate your original class if it's private?

Say one of your apps is a web application, that needs to store a product's image as a url instead of a file path? Or to add caching, logging or something else on top of Product?

Comment: paolo, would you say you were making a case for public classes with virtual members?

Comment: @RobGlynn yes I would, although a combination of IoC containers and the decorator pattern makes it easier to compose behaviors and does not require methods to be virtual.

Answer (score 0):

There are way too many questions here in order to determine the best way.

If these applications can reuse the additional functionality given by the classes in your DAL, then I'd say absolutely reuse them.

Taking "Product" for example.  If the DAL has a definition of Product that is pretty close to or the same as the definition the applications need, then reuse is your best bet.

---

If the applications explicitly do NOT want the functionality given by the classes and instead want to provide their own implementation, then just use the interfaces.

Again, looking at "Product": if the applications have their own definition of Product with perhaps additional or just plain different properties and methods then they should implement the interface.

---

It's really a question of how the classes in question are going to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Returning interfaces is better but then you will need GetProducts() to know about those implementations to properly query the data store. You might want to use an IOC framework for that.

Comment: I would recommend you return IQueryable instead of List.